# If $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0 - h)}{2h} = f'(x_0)$ exists, is f differentiable at $x_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I'm not too sure where to start. Any help will be appreciated.

If $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0 - h)}{2h} = f'(x_0)$ exists, is f differentiable at $x_0$?

Comment: look http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594098/suppose-f-is-differentiable-on-an-interval-i-prove-that-f-is-bounded-on-i-if-a the third answer

Comment: better rephrase the header and say just that the limit exits (drop $f'(x_0)$). If you say $f'(x_0)$, well then, yes it exists!

Comment: BTW this is called [symmetric derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative).

Comment: A very similar question was asked a few days ago here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582838/does-it-imply-f-is-differentiable-on-mathbb-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Look for a function $f$ which makes the numerator $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)$ identically zero. Geometrically this means that the graph of $f$ is symmetric with respect to the line $\{x=x_0 \}$.

Comment: Wow that was dumb of me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

$f(x) = |x|$. Look at the function at the nbd of $0$.